# Any way to embed a Swing JFrame in the AWT Frame from the SWT_AWT bridge?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, swt, awt

I'm integrating a Swing application into an [Bioclipse](http://bioclipse.net)/Eclipse plug-in, and since Eclipse uses SWT, I have to use the SWT_AWT bridge somehow.

The problem is that the starting point I get from the SWT_AWT bridge is an AWT Frame, like so:

```
 java.awt.Frame awtFrame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(composite);
```

... (which can be filled with AWT components), but the situation is that the Swing application contains much of it's functionality in it's main JFrame component. Now, a Swing JFrame can not be integrated as is into an AWT Frame.

Refactoring of the original Swing application has been discussed with the developer of the original application. Just wanted to make sure we didn't miss any obvious workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Swing-SWT-Integration/index.html) is an excellent article on how to use Swing inside your SWT/RCP apps. This should be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. It does not give an answer to my problem, but that might of course be the answer too, that this is not possible really, so I'll accept your answer unless somebody comes up with a working workaround.'