# How to embed a jframe in an eclipse view

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jframe, awt, jpanel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to embed a Swing JFrame in the AWT Frame from the SWT_AWT bridge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502897/any-way-to-embed-a-swing-jframe-in-the-awt-frame-from-the-swt-awt-bridge)

I have an RCP application with many views.
I have a class which extends JPanel and draws some things.
Is there any way to embed this class to be shown inside a view?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Composite swtAwtComponent = new Composite(parent, SWT.EMBEDDED);
    java.awt.Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame( swtAwtComponent );
    javax.swing.JPanel panel = new javax.swing.JPanel( );
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.add(jFrameClass)
```